# Google Play services out of date. Requires 11020000 but found 10298470

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest

I constantly get this error. My phone is google play services version 11.0.55, my virtual phone is 10.2.98. I've looked into error areas similar to this one, but I've always received an error. Please help.Do you have any idea?

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tatlicilar.visualeducation"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  }
  dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.next:recycler:1.5.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.next:recycler:1.5.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Delete your emulator and create it again with the latest version

Comment: But only my virtual phone works. How do I do that on my phone?

Comment: Can you try updating your real device's Google Play Services from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en)?